# ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.LandTrendrFit output bands completely masked

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

When I take the vertices array image from a run of the Landtrendr algorithm on an image collection and input it back into the LandTrendrFit function with another image collection, the output (e.g. 'B1_fit') is completely masked. I've not been able to find anything online about this specific function, so I was wondering if anyone could show me what I was doing wrong.

I originally encountered problems applying LandTrendrFit to a different image collection, but I can't even get it to work on the original image collection. See below:

```
var medoidCollection = getMedoidCollection();



var nbrCollection = medoidCollection.map(function(image) {
    return image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B7']).rename('NBR').multiply(-1).addBands(image).set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
});


var landtrendrOutput = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.LandTrendr({
    timeSeries: nbrCollection,
    maxSegments:9,
    spikeThreshold:0.9,
    vertexCountOvershoot:3,
    preventOneYearRecovery:true,
    recoveryThreshold:0.25,
    pvalThreshold:0.05,
    bestModelProportion:0.75,
    minObservationsNeeded:6
});

var vertices = landtrendrOutput.select(['LandTrendr']).arraySlice(0, 3, 4).arrayProject([1]);

var landtrendrFitOutput= ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.LandTrendrFit(nbrCollection, vertices);

Map.addLayer(landtrendrFitOutput);
```

When `landtrendrFitOutput` is added to the Map, the inspector shows that all of the bands ('NBR_fit', 'B1_fit', etc.) are masked in the area covered by nbrCollection, despite the vertices image covering the entire aoi with the expected arrays of 1s and 0s.

Just for info, I've tried clipping the vertices image to the geometry of the original images and not projecting the sliced array to 1 dimension, neither of which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake on my part - the "vertices" parameter in LandTrendrFit isn't the isVertex row of the 'LandTrendr' band, but rather the years row masked by the isVertex row.

That is, instead of arrays like [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], the vertices image must comprise arrays like [2006, 2008, 2012] (i.e. the array [2006, 2007, ..., 2012] arrayMasked() by [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]).

My code instead should have looked like the following:

```
var medoidCollection = getMedoidCollection();



var nbrCollection = medoidCollection.map(function(image) {
    return image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B7']).rename('NBR').multiply(-1).addBands(image).set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
});


var landtrendrOutput = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.LandTrendr({
    timeSeries: nbrCollection,
    maxSegments:9,
    spikeThreshold:0.9,
    vertexCountOvershoot:3,
    preventOneYearRecovery:true,
    recoveryThreshold:0.25,
    pvalThreshold:0.05,
    bestModelProportion:0.75,
    minObservationsNeeded:6
});

var vertices = landtrendrOutput.select(['LandTrendr']).arraySlice(0, 3, 4).arrayProject([1]);

var years = landtrendrOutput.select(['LandTrendr']).arraySlice(0, 0, 1).arrayProject([1]);

var maskedYears = years.arrayMask(vertices);

var landtrendrFitOutput= ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.LandTrendrFit(nbrCollection, maskedYears);

Map.addLayer(landtrendrFitOutput);
```